# Flash - ExternalInterface error with google iFrame

Tags: flash, apache-flex, iframe, swfobject, externalinterface

A couple of weeks ago, without any code changes, we started seeing the following error message in our application (those with debug version of flash) when trying to navigate to a page containing a google iFrame:

```
Error: [object Error]
    at flash.external::ExternalInterface$/_toAS()
    at flash.external::ExternalInterface$/call()
    at com.google.code.flexiframe::IFrame/hideIFrame()
    at com.google.code.flexiframe::IFrame/updateFrameVisibility()
    at com.google.code.flexiframe::IFrame/handleChange()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.containers::ViewStack/dispatchChangeEvent()
    at mx.containers::ViewStack/commitProperties()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/validateProperties()
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateProperties()
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiationCallback()
```

Our application is an SWF which is embedded into a jsp page using google's swfobject.js with the following params:

```
        params.quality = "high";
        params.bgcolor = "#ffffff";
        params.allowscriptaccess = "sameDomain";
        params.allowfullscreen = "true";
        params.SeamlessTabbing = "false";
swfobject.embedSWF("flex/App.swf", "container", "100%", "100%", swfVersionStr, expressInstall, flashvars, params, attributes);
```

It runs on WAS (Websphere) 7 servers. Our page containing the iFrame is defined very simply:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        [Bindable]
        [Inject]
        public var mainModel:MainModel;

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <parsley:Configure/>
</fx:Declarations>

<iframe:IFrame id="iframeSDM" width="100%" height="100%" overlayDetection="true" source="{mainModel.sdmUrl}"/>
```

A colleague suggested that it was to do with the creation/initialization order, so I tried adding `creationPolicy="all"` on the `<s:NavigatorContent>` for the screen, but this merely changes the timing of the error from navigation to app start up.

From what I can tell, we have always had this error for some reason, but it has been suppressed. I added logging, and it appears that some "outside force" is setting `ExternalInterface.marshallExceptions = true`. I am not a flex expert, so don't even know the scope of this variable (ie, can another application on the box be changing it?).

I would like to know what is causing this error (the error message is not very informative!) and how we can fix it.

I would also like to know why it would be the case that marshallExceptions suddenly gets set to true without us making any code changes, but that's secondary to getting the problem fixed :).